# Best way to find the difference between 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these 2 arrays of objects.

[image]

> Sorry that I post the image because I want you guys to quickly understand my points.

What is the best way to compare 2 arrays of objects and look for what is not in it?

I can do 2 levels for loops and an if-check, but I'm not sure if it is the best approach.
I am seeking a better performance JS way to achieve something like this.

This is what I am looking to extract while comparing `arr1` & `arr2`.

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Date and Time"
}
```

Comment: To list objects in `arr2` that are not present in `arr1`, please try: `console.log(arr2.filter(a2 => !arr1.some(({ id, name }) => id === a2.id && name === a2.name )));` and share your feedback.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation. I also added the test suite link in the answer. So that you can compare the performance

Answer (score 2):

One way is to concatenate both arrays together, then iterate and filter to see if that id exists in both arrays. If it doesn't exist in both arrays, it's extra.

```
a1.concat(a2).filter(a => a1.findIndex(f => f.id === a.id) == -1 || a2.findIndex(f => f.id === a.id) == -1)
```

```js
let arr1 = [{"id": 1,"name": "Date and Time"},{"id": 2,"name": "Date and Time"},{"id": 3,"name": "Date and Time"},{"id": 4,"name": "Date and Time"}]

let arr2 = [{"id": 1,"name": "Date and Time"},{"id": 2,"name": "Date and Time"},{"id": 3,"name": "Date and Time"}]

const findMissing = (a1, a2) => a1.concat(a2).filter(a => a1.findIndex(f => f.id === a.id) == -1 || a2.findIndex(f => f.id === a.id) == -1)

console.log(findMissing(arr1, arr2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Different ways to achieve this requirement. I also created a performance check based on all the below 3 solutions [here](https://jsbench.me/e8l3e40mnt/1). Kindly run this test suite and based on the result you can use any of the below solution in your project.

1. Filtered out the array by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and find the id in the another array by using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}];

const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}, {
    id: 4,
  name: "Date and Time"
}];

const res = arr2.filter((obj) => !arr1.find(({ id }) => obj.id === id));

console.log(res);
```

2. By using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}];

const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}, {
    id: 4,
  name: "Date and Time"
}];

const IDArray = arr1.map(obj => obj.id);

const res = arr2.filter(obj => !IDArray.includes(obj.id));

console.log(res);
```

3. Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) along with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}];

const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
  name: "Weather"
}, {
    id: 2,
  name: "Geo Location"
}, {
    id: 3,
  name: "Device"
}, {
    id: 4,
  name: "Date and Time"
}];

const res = arr2.filter(({ id }) => !arr1.some(x => x.id == id))

console.log(res)
```